# Router.Navigate does not call service in component

Tags: angular, service, angular2-services

I have below service

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class LoggedInUserService {
constructor( ) {
    console.log('constructor call');
    }
 }
```

the constructor is being called when 'acctPage' page directly loaded like doing refresh
But when I get navigated by a page like

```
this.router.navigate(['/acctPage']);
```

The constructor does not call.

I have created an object in the constructor of acctPage

```
constructor(private ser serviceName)
```

I tried creating one project
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zje9ww?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts

But since I am new not able to complete this

What I am missing

Comment: Can you create a minimal repro on StackBlitz? It probably has to do with the place where the service is injected but it's hard to tell with this information.

Comment: A service defined like this is a singleton. So it's only created once. So its constructor is only invoked once. Why would it be invoked when you navigate to some route?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it does make sense because thats what a constructor does. It's being called only once when the page is being constructed, that's why when you refresh the page it's being called. From now on the router will use the constructed component and won't need to build it again and again every time a router link is clicked.

Comment: Nope, I mean to say when I use this.router.navigate(['/acctPage']); on login page it redirects the user to acctPage but constructor not called, but when I directly hitting acctpage it gets called

Comment: @Md.ParvezAlam again, why do you think this should happen? Where in the Angular documentation is it written that, if you define a service and navigate to a route, then the constructor of the service will be called? Why would that happen? Read the documentation about services. They don't work using like you think they work.

Comment: Sorry I have just started angular so could be foolish qstns. Do you mean to say If I create object of service in different components (say 3) , and If I use router.navigate it will be called once in app, it won't be called when I navigate to diff components.?

Comment: Service constructor is called only once in angular project. So yes.